# "empty vocabulary" error for spam classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, vectorization

I'm trying to make a spam classifier and I've used the following code to do so.

But the issue is that I'm getting an error stating that my program has an "empty library" and that "My document has nothing but stop words".

Do you know what's causing this?

```
import os
import io
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB


def readFiles(path):
    for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            path = os.path.join(root, filename)

            inBody = False
            lines = []
            f = io.open(path, 'r', encoding='latin1')
            for line in f:
                if inBody:
                    lines.append(line)
                elif line == '\n':
                    inBody = True
            f.close()
            message = '\n'.join(lines)
            yield path, message


def dataFrameFromDirectory(path, classification):
    rows = []
    index = []
    for filename, message in readFiles(path):
        rows.append({'message': message, 'class': classification})
        index.append(filename)

    return DataFrame(rows, index=index)


data = DataFrame({'message': [], 'class': []})

data = data.append(dataFrameFromDirectory('C:/Users/Tapan/Desktop/enron/enron1/spam', 'spam'))
data = data.append(dataFrameFromDirectory('C:/Users/Tapan/Desktop/enron/enron1/ham', 'ham'))

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
counts = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['message'].values)

classifier = MultinomialNB()
targets = data['class'].values
classifier.fit(counts, targets)

examples = ['prescribed online and shipped overnight to your door', 'vastar owns 68% of the gross production']
examples_counts = vectorizer.transform(examples)
predictions = classifier.predict(examples_counts)

print(predictions)
```

Comment: Instead of putting a largish code snippet and expecting people to read through it on their own, why not break it down into sections and put in some comments also

Comment: Even better than following @DeepakSaini's advice would be to do some debugging and to isolate the parts of the code whence errors arise.  Why, for example, burden us with `readFiles` if you are confident that it works correctly ?  And if you are not confident that it works correctly, test and (where necessary) correct it until it does.